# When are function templates resolved in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, runtime, compile-time

I am a novice c++ programmer and I've been trying to learn more about the language through reading multiple books about the language. There is a section in a book i'm currently reading that talks about how smart pointers have different strategy for using the custom deleter provided by the user(i.e. unique pointer takes a custom deleter through its second template argument, while shared pointer takes it through a normal function/constructor argument)
and I got really confused at this paragraph

> Although we don’t know how the library types are implemented, we can
>   infer that shared_ptr must access its deleter indirectly. That is the
>   deleter must be stored as a pointer or as a class that encapsulates a
>   pointer. We can be certain that shared_ptr does not hold the deleter
>   as a direct member, because the type of the deleter isn’t known until
>   run time. Indeed, we can change the type of the deleter in a given
>   shared_ptr during that shared_ptr’s lifetime. We can construct a
>   shared_ptr using a deleter of one type, and subsequently use reset to
>   give that same shared_ptr a different type of deleter. In general, we
>   cannot have a member whose type changes at run time. Hence, the
>   deleter must be stored indirectly.

Here it states that the deleter type isn't known until run time, but I thought that all templates are resolved during compile time, so I can see the shared pointer class using something like `void (*del)(T* p)` where del points to the deleter passed, and T is the value type of the object pointed to by the shared pointer. so isn't the type, in this case, known during compile time?
If someone can also provide me with their idea of how the shared pointer class implements their deleter pointer, (in case mine is wrong which I'm sure it is) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section primarily seems to talk about where the deleter is stored. To store a deleter with a known type in the actual `std::shared_ptr<T>` object its concrete type would need to be known at compile time. Most likely, this type would be

```
void (*deleter)(T*);
```

However, a `std::shared_ptr<B>` where `B` is a `public` base of `D` can be constructed with a `D*`, e.g.,:

```
struct B {};
struct D: B {};
std::shared_ptr<B>(new D);
```

For the above code to work correctly, the `std::shared_ptr<B>` would need to store a `void (*)(D*)` for the deleter. However, function pointer types do not convert to each other.

Thus, the conclusion is that `std::shared_ptr<T>` stores the deleter in a maintenance record it needs to keep anyway to deal with the reference count. This records is likely to contain a suitable object holding the actual deleter. It could, e.g., consist of a record which is specific for the type `D` but be commonly used by all `std::shared_ptr<T>`. How this record looks exactly, I don't know and it seems it won't be entirely trivial to deal with all its requirements. A rough draft might look like this:

```
struct shared_ptr_count_record {
    virtual void destroy(void* ptr) = 0;
    // something else
};
template <typename D>
struct shared_ptr_deleter
    : shared_ptr_count_record {
    // something else
    void destroy(void* ptr) override {
        delete static_cast<D*>(ptr);
    }
};
template <typename T>
class shared_ptr {
    shared_ptr_count_record* record;
public:
    template <typename C>
    shared_ptr(C* ptr): record(new shared_ptr_deleter<C>(ptr)) {}
    ~shared_ptr() {
         if (this->record->release()) {
            this->record->destroy(this->get());
         }
    }
    // some other stuff
};
```

That is, the function templates themselves are created at compile time. However, a `std::shared_ptr<T>` can only know the actually used deleter function until run-time.

Answer (score 0):

If `shared_ptr` used a deleter of the type you mentioned (`(*del)(T* p)`), that would preclude using a function object or even a bound member function pointer. Instead I'm sure it uses something similar to `std::function` to store the deleter. The deleter representation effectively `erases` the type and is left just with something that it knows can be called with a single argument of type `T`.